# ASP.Net response empty for recursive types

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I was writing a Rest endpoint and for some reason the rest calls themselves kept returning empty content even though debugging the code revealed that the Response's `Content` was defined as I expected it to be. The same problem did not manifest itself for similar calls. Eventually, I realized that the difference between the calls that worked and the calls that failed was that the unsuccessful calls attempted to return recursive (types with public properties/fields of that type) or mutually recursive types while the successful calls did not. As a minimal example of the problem I encountered:

```
[RoutePrefix("")]
public class LoopyController
{
    public class Loopy
    {
        public Loopy Self {get; set;}
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("loopy")]
    public HttpResponseMessage LoopyCall()
    {
        Loopy loopy = new Loopy();
        loopy.Self = loopy;
        return Request.CreateResponse(loopy)
    }
}
```

A `GET` call on the `loopy` endpoint returns an empty response. I would expect it to either hang or throw an exception. I would like to know why ASP.Net exhibits this behavior. I recognize that a solution to this problem is to modify the return value so that it is no longer recursive in anyway, but would like to know if there is a cleaner method of resolving this issue.

Edit:

There's been discussion in the comments about my use of the term 'recursive type'. I am confident going by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type that `Loopy` is a recursive type. *However*, the problem is not so much that the type `Loopy` is recursive but that the object `loopy` has a circular reference. The following endpoint:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("notsoloopy")]
public HttpResponseMessage NotSoLoopy()
{
    Loopy notSoLoopy = new Loopy();
    notSoLoopy.Self = null;
    return Request.CreateResponse(notSoLoopy);
}
```

returns the response `{}` in reply to a `GET` request. Of course `Loopy` being recursive enables `loopy`'s having a circular reference.

Comment: @Liam Yes. I should have specified that it is also ASP.Net v4.0.

Comment: This is not recursion, it is a circular reference. WebAPI json formatter is set to ignore circular references by default. Even if you're using XML I am thinking (but not sure) this is ignored anyway. This article might provide some insight: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hongyes/archive/2012/09/04/loop-reference-handling-in-serializer.aspx

Comment: @Liam, The issue is not with the access modifier but with the circular reference. I did not know about that restriction, though, thanks.

Comment: @Dmitriy -- this is a known use of the term 'recursive' (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type). Thank you for the blog link, it was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Semantics :) I rather prefer to make a distinction between the two, since in this case it is the same instance not just the same type.

Comment: @DmitriyDavidKhaykin That's why the question called it a "recursive type" and not recursion. Seems fairly clear to me :)

Comment: True. Regardless, glad that the article was useful to OP.

Comment: Recursive data type does not mean instances of that type will have circular references (i.e. valid linked list is recursive type but no circular references, but you can use the same type to built circular buffer)

Comment: @Liam I wasn't going to since I felt it would kind of be milking it for rep, but hey, you twised my arm :) Answer is up.

Comment: Also this is very much a circular reference and not a recursive type, from the link in wiki page you added: *data type for values that may contain other values of the same* **type**. Note *type* not same **object**.

Comment: @Liam that was my interpretation from reading the wiki as well. In essence it seems we can say that a circular reference may be a kind of recursive type (since it does have a property of the same type) and therefore a circular reference is always of a recursive type, but a recursive type is not guaranteed to be a circular reference. I'm not really attached either way, however it is important in this case to note that this is a circular reference, whether or not it is also a recursive type, since that is the central part of the issue OP was experiencing.

Comment: @Liam The type `Loopy` is definitely recursive. However, the basic problem is that the object `loopy` has a circular reference. See my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a circular reference. WebAPI json formatter is set to ignore circular references by default. Even if you're using XML I am thinking (but not sure) this is ignored anyway. [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hongyes/archive/2012/09/04/loop-reference-handling-in-serializer.aspx) might provide some insight:

> Json.net serializer (*the serializer used in web api*) supports to ignore circular reference on global
>   setting.

Comment: Just commented the relevant part of the article and tidied up a bit :)

Comment: Thanks! Looks much better :)